# Adding new leaf to jTree node

Tags: java, swing

Let's say, I have this code of a jTree

```
    JTree jTree = new JTree() ;
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("root") ;
    jTree.setModel( new DefaultTreeModel(root));

    DefaultMutableTreeNode firstNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("first node") ;
```

Now I want to add a leaf into the node named "first node" ( which is currently a leaf ) from a place where firstNode variable is not available. How can it be done?

Clearification:
Okey! I have a JFrame in a class (extends swing) and a jTree is a private member of this class. Now I pass this class object (as a parameter) into another class method where the jTree is supposed to be populated. But I couldn't do anything with that **jTree** from another class method. (Of course accessing private method is not my problem :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
firstNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("leaf node"));
```

UPDATE: As per your comments, you must have a reference to the node under which you want to add the new leaf. If you are responding to an tree selection event in the tree, then you can get the reference by this:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode firstNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)jTree.getSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent();
```

Comment: Sorry my fault! I forgot to tell that, the firstNode variable is not available where I want to append something in it.

Comment: @Dewsworld...see my edit if it helps. Otherwise you have to clearify your problem.

Comment: Dear @Swaranga Sarma. As a new java guy, I'm silly at clarifying my problem. I've edited my question with a clarification. Now, you may wish to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Be careful, structure modification are not notified automatically. With a default model, you can just use:

```
treeModel.insertNodeInto(newChild, parent, index)
```

In your case, I don't understand what's available, and what's not…

Comment: +1 for notification, just a minor quirk: none of the node modifications (neither structure nor content) are notified automatically